# Winsock send function waits indefinitely

Tags: c, winsock

In this code, send function doesn't block but doesn't send either.
If I call shutdown , then it is forced to send.

How do I make this code send a small message within a second or so?

This code is suppose to respond to web browser GET request.
(User types localhost:27015)
It is just a test, I do not need it for work or a bigger project.

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")


int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {

WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult = 0;

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
sockaddr_in service;

iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData); 

ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

service.sin_family = AF_INET;
service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
service.sin_port = htons(27015);

iResult = bind(ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR *)& service, sizeof(service));

listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);

auto AcceptSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

char getbuf[400];

recv(AcceptSocket, getbuf, 400, NULL);
getbuf[399] = '\0';

printf("%s",getbuf);

char str[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Date: Sun, 19 May 2018 08 : 56 : 53 GMT\r\n"
"Server : Apache / 2.2.14 (Win32)\r\n"
"Last - Modified : Sat, 20 Nov 2004 07 : 16 : 26 GMT\r\n"
"ETag : \"10000000565a5-2c-3e94b66c2e680\" \r\n"
"Accept - Ranges : bytes\r\n"
"Content - Length : 44\r\n"
"Connection : close\r\n"
"Content - Type : text / html\r\n"
"X - Pad : avoid browser bug\r\n\r\n"

"<html><body><h1>It works!</h1> </body> </html>\r\n\0";


char *sendbuf = (char*)str;
iResult = send(AcceptSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(str), 0);

//shutdown(AcceptSocket, SD_BOTH); //forces to send

while (1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (1);` will stop the program indefinitely.

Comment: Also all the headers are wrong, and the Content-length is 48 not 44, and you should care about what `recv()` returns.

Comment: But it is after the send function. Firefox is waiting unless I uncomment shutdown function.

Comment: With HTTP 1.1 or higher, the browser uses the same TCP session to perform multiple requests. After it is done receiving the data it asked for, it will make more requests during the same connection. If your application is not prepared to handle that, the browser might hang. Since you are obviously experimenting HTTP for the first time, I recommend you use HTTP 1.0, and just terminate the connection after sending data. Also, in that model, specifying Content-Length is optional.

Comment: At this stage I only care to make the send function send without shutdown function

Comment: It is sending, but because your headers are written like crap the browser doesn't know you were done sending. Without a meaningful Content-Length, it assumed the data will be complete only when the connection is terminated.

Comment: Browser displays the html if I use the shutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char str[] = 
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
"Date: Sun, 19 May 2018 08:56:53 GMT\r\n"
"Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Win32)\r\n"
"Last-Modified: Sat, 20 Nov 2004 07:16:26 GMT\r\n"
"ETag: \"10000000565a5-2c-3e94b66c2e680\"\r\n"
"Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n"
"Content-Length: 46\r\n"
"Connection: close\r\n"
"Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
"X-Pad: avoid browser bug\r\n\r\n"
"<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>\r\n";
```

The browser isn't a person, it doesn't know what the hell is `Content - Type :`, it doesn't recognize `08 : 56 : 53` as a valid time, there is no MIME type called `text / html`. Stop putting spaces where there shouldn't be any, the browser doesn't have a brain, it can't guess.

Also you are explicitly telling the connection will close after the data is sent, with the header `Connection: close`, but you are not doing that. If you intent to keep the connection alive, then use `Connection: keep-alive`.

Moreover, your data is not 44 bytes in length.

Comment: I used your header with keep-alive ,and now it works, thanks.